# Cypress: Electron doesn't support .finally()?

Tags: electron, cypress, finally

Electron 3.x added support to javascript `.finally()`

I have a problem with this because my Vue app is actually using .finally when handling axios requests.

And running cypress tests using electron fails due to `.finally()`. ...

> I cannot ask the team to refactor code for a problem only with a test suite and only with the 'auto' mode because we're still working on local culture to accept to spend time across testing. If I ask this to the devs, someone will shutdown testing...

Question: **Is there a way to make Electron able to digest this syntax?**

The webapp is made with Laravel 5.8.x, Vue 2, and axios, transpiled by webmix (webpack chain).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. either upgrade cypress to `3.5.0`, which [uses](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#3-5-0) Electron 5.
2. or, use a polyfill.

   First, install the [es-shims/Promise.prototype.finally](https://github.com/es-shims/Promise.prototype.finally):

   ```
   npm install -D promise.prototype.finally
   ```

   Then, in your `cypress/support/index.js`:

   ```js
   const { implementation: FinallyPolyfill } = require('promise.prototype.finally');

   function loadPolyfill ( win ) {
       win.Promise.prototype.finally = FinallyPolyfill;
   }

   // polyfill AUT's Promise
   Cypress.on('window:before:load', win => {
       loadPolyfill(win);
   });

   // polyfill Cypress runner's wrapper window Promise
   before(() => {
       loadPolyfill(window);
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer; I cannot upgrade to 3.5 because a bug that breaks test involving iframes (like stripe official sdk)